# Modal Popup validation on Enter key

Tags: jquery

I'm new to JQuery and I'm trying out the modal popup form example with some edits. The example had a Name, Email, and Password in the form. I only wanted the Email, so I removed the other two. Before removing them, the form wasn't submitting on Enter, but only when I clicked the button. After removing them, the form will now submit on Enter and skip the Email validation.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          $(function () {

              //Modal pop-up form
              // a workaround for a flaw in the demo system (http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4375), ignore!
              $("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");

              var email = $("#email"),
                      allFields = $([]).add(email),
                      tips = $(".validateTips");

              function updateTips(t) {
                  tips
                          .text(t)
                          .addClass("ui-state-highlight");
                  setTimeout(function () {
                      tips.removeClass("ui-state-highlight", 1500);
                  }, 500);
              }

              function checkLength(o, n, min, max) {
                  if (o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min) {
                      o.addClass("ui-state-error");
                      updateTips("Length of " + n + " must be between " +
                              min + " and " + max + ".");
                      return false;
                  } else {
                      return true;
                  }
              }

              function checkRegexp(o, regexp, n) {
                  if (!(regexp.test(o.val()))) {
                      o.addClass("ui-state-error");
                      updateTips(n);
                      return false;
                  } else {
                      return true;
                  }
              }

              $("#dialog-form").dialog({
                  autoOpen: false,
                  height: 350,
                  width: 350,
                  modal: true,
                  buttons: {
                      "Send Login": function () {
                          var bValid = true;
                          allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");

                          bValid = bValid && checkLength(email, "email", 6, 80);

                          // From jquery.validate.js (by joern), contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
                          bValid = bValid && checkRegexp(email, /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i, "Please enter a valid email address.");

                          if (bValid) {
                              $("#users tbody").append("<tr>" +
                                      "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" +
                                  "</tr>");
                              $(this).dialog("close");
                              $("form[name='modalPopup']").submit()
                          }

                      },
                      Cancel: function () {
                          $(this).dialog("close");
                      }
                  },
                  close: function () {
                      allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
                  }
              });

              $("#send-password")

                      .click(function () {
                          $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
                      });


          });
              </script>
```

And here is my form:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Send My Login">
                  Enter the email address associated with your account. Your password will be sent to you.
                  <br />
                  <strong>If you do not have an email address</strong>, or do not
                  remember it, please contact your Human Resources department to have your login
                  provided to you.

                  <p class="validateTips"></p>

                  <form action="SendLogin.asp" method="Post" name="modalPopup">
                  <fieldset>

                      <label for="email">Email</label>
                      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />

                  </fieldset>
                  </form>
              </div>
```

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: Email validation regexes do not work.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are missing a button

```
<button id="send-password">a button</button>
```

this should call

```
$("#send-password")
  .click(function () {
    $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm not missing a button.  I actually have that further down on the page, I just didn't include it in the code.  The pop up is opening fine.  My issue is that when I hit Enter it's bypassing the validation and submitting the form.  Any other ideas?